# cant install rtl8723ae wireless driver for lenovo yoga "11"s

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek

I recently downloaded 12.10 on my lenovo yoga "11"s.

I My problem now is that I have no internet neither wifi nor ether. Only on my windows 8 partition does it work.

I have downloaded several driver packages from various sources. None of them work with their instructions.I cd into the rtl downloaded and extracted folder and then hit make. Then it tells me no such file or directory. I know it is there but no go.

This is from the terminal

```
owner@home:~/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012$ sudo su 
root@home:/home/owner/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012# make install 
make -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build M=/home/owner/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012 modules 
make: *** /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop. 
make: *** [all] Error 2 
root@home:/home/owner/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012# ^C 
root@home:/home/owner/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012#
```

Comment: In order to compile this, you would also need build-essential and linux-headers-generic and _all_ their dependencies. If you install 14.04, the driver is installed and working by default.

Comment: Try with installing common wifi drivers in ubuntu  `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree wicd wicd-gtk wicd-daemon` . Then use the device with wicd.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get 14.04 working by following the ['wireless woes' part of this tutorial](http://sudomasochism.com/post/55464266362/installing-ubuntu-linux-on-a-lenovo-yoga-11s). You'll need an internet connection to download the tarball from github but here's the gist:

```
wget -qO- https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au/archive/master.tar.gz | tar -zxvf -
cd rtl8723au-master
make
sudo make install
```

Then reboot and your wireless should work now.

For installing ubuntu I only needed to shrink the windows 8.1 partition, within Windows choose to "Reboot and start from USB". Didn't need to use anything else. There's a lot of conflicting info about this but the situation for installing ubuntu alongside seems to have improved greatly. No need for complicated install guidelines any more (getting windows to reboot to USB is the most difficult).

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I ended up wiping 12.1 and installing 14.04. I still had the problem with the wireless card not recognized but this time when I downloaded the drivers from dropbox, they worked.

Answer (score -1):

Please note that this will only work if you have the Realtek wireless card.

You can verify this by typing: `lsusb`
If you see something similar to:

> Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:1724 Realtek Semiconductor Corp

you have this wireless card, and it is not automatically supported/installed with your ubuntu installation.

Assuming you have gotten ubuntu installed, use a computer with internet and download this file:

https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au/archive/master.zip

After doing so, boot your linux system and unzip the file in your desktop, or some accessible location.

Go into terminal and change your directory to the rtl8723au you just made, and type `make`

It will compile and after, type `sudo make install`